# Understanding how await keyword in event loop

Tags: dart, asynchronous, async-await

How await keyword work in dart?

I have simple future like this

```
main() {
  
  print('Start');
 
  Future((){
    print('From Future');
  });

  print('end');
}

// Output
// Start
// End
// From Future
```

Thats is work as i expected, because dart internally will be execute synchronous code at the main first, if all synchronous code have executed so dart will be run event loop and put the code of future into event queue. This is reason why my future executed lastly.

So if i put await keyword into my future the output will be synchronous, even i put a heavy computation inside a future they still running as a synchronous.

```
main() {
  
  print('Start');
 
  await Future((){
    print('From Future');
  });

  print('end');
}

// Output
// Start
// From Future
// End
```

So my question is how the await keyword really work in dart? if i use that this mean a still run synchronous code? this will be useless right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `await` keyword in Dart is, in short, just a nicer way to write async logic compared to using `.then()` statements. So your second method is going to be executed as if it was written as:

```dart
Future<void> main() {
  print('Start');

  return Future(() {
    print('From Future');
  }).then((_) {
    print('end');
  });
}
```

As you can see, we don't change the fact that `main()` are being executed in sync, but it will at `await` just immediately return a `Future` and the rest of the code is going to be executed at some later point in time.

In this example, it does not look like we are saving a lot by using `await` but for more complex code, it can become a nightmare of nested `.then()` statements.

But `await` does give us this "illusion" that our code is being executed synchronous. But in reality, we are allowing other events to be executed when we have an `await`.